# I can't understand what is the error in this code

Tags: javascript, jquery

I can't understand why Firefox gives me error in line 31 saying that elencouser (that I declared on top of my code) is null, please help me if you can, thanks

```
var elencouser = [];
var array;

$(document).ready(function(){

    if (typeof(Storage) !== "undefined") {

        if(sessionStorage.getItem("arrayuser") == "undefined"){
            elencouser[0] = new utente("admin","admin","Danilo","Cerasi");
            array = JSON.stringify(elencouser);
            sessionStorage.setItem("arrayuser",array);
        }

        $("#registrati").click(function(){

            array = sessionStorage.getItem("arrayuser");
            elencouser = $.parseJSON(array);

            var email=$("#exampleInputEmail").val();        //prendo quello che ha scritto l'utente
            var password=$("#exampleInputPassword").val();
            var nome=$("#exampleFirstName").val();
            var cognome=$("#exampleLastName").val();

            elencouser.push( new utente(email,password,nome,cognome) );
            alert("sei appena stato registrato! Ora verrai reindirizzato alla pagina di login..");

            location.href="login.html";
        });

    }else{
        alert("riscontriamo problemi di apertura con il browser che stai utilizzando, aggiornalo oppure prova con uno doverso");    //se il browser non supporta il il session storage glielo dico
    }
});
```

Comment: Which one is line 31 - `elencouser.push(` ? I guess then that you're getting null back from `$.parseJSON` a few lines above. I think your code that tries to detect if the value is missing and initialise it is wrong.

Comment: i put "undefined" with " ", thaks a lot ;D     now it works

Comment: Either `array` or `elencouser` are null. So, either `sessionStorage.getItem("arrayuser");` is returning null, either `$.parseJSON(array);` is returning null. Can you please log both?

Answer (score 3):

The undefined check should use `typeof` to check against `"undefined"`

i.e.

```js
if(typeof sessionStorage.getItem("arrayuser") == "undefined"){
```

Note that `arrayuser` might still contain different data due to various reasons (either by manual editing by the user, or by legacy code).

Thus I would always assume you might not get a valid array back when getting `arrayuser` from the local/session storage.

In your click event I would also check if `arrayuser` is valid, and if it's an array:

```js
try {
    const arrayuser = sessionStorage.getItem("arrayuser");
    elencouser = JSON.parse(arrayuser);

    if(!Array.isArray(elencouser)) throw "arrayuser was not a valid array";
} catch(e) {
    console.error(e);
    elencouser = [];
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Rup, Looks like I missed that at first glance :)

Comment: There's any number of reasons why the sessionStorage could change between the initial check and the click event - much better to check it as you need it as demonstrated in this answer.

Comment: (unless the value is being set to `" "` which is implied by OPs comments to the question)